# Problem implementing pure virtual class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have the following class:

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include "map.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef CONTAINER_H_
#define CONTAINER_H_

struct PathContainer {
    int x, y;
    string path;
};

class Container {
public:
    virtual void AddTile(string, FloorTile *) = 0;
    virtual void ClearContainer() = 0;
    virtual PathContainer *NextTile() = 0;
};

class StackImpl : public Container {
private:
    stack<PathContainer> cntr;
public:
    StackImpl();
    void AddTile(string, NeighborTile *);
    void ClearContainer();
    PathContainer *NextTile();
};

class QueueImpl : public Container {
private:
    queue<PathContainer> cntr;
public:
    QueueImpl();
    void AddTile(string, NeighborTile *);
    void ClearContainer();
    PathContainer *NextTile();
};
#endif
```

When I try creating StackImpl or QueueImpl object like so:

```
Container *cntr;
cntr = new StackImpl();
```

or

```
Container *cntr;
cntr = new QueueImpl();
```

I get the following error at compile:

> escape.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
> escape.cpp:26: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘StackImpl’
> container.h:23: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘StackImpl’:
> container.h:18: note:   virtual void Container::AddTile(std::string, FloorTile*)

Any ideas?

Comment: Note also that your base class should almost certainly have a virtual destructor (don't make it pure virtual, just virtual).

Comment: Never ever place `using namespace std;` - or any `using namespace` declarations for that matter - in a header file. You'll be imposing that declaration on every source file that includes your header, so it is considered a very bad practice.

Comment: @Praetorian: In principle I agree (and so I +1 you, good sir), but at least `std` is, well, `std`. Of all the namespaces to globally use, it's probably the least evil. :)

Comment: @Jonathan:  I'd actually argue that it's the most evil because it is so expansive and because there are so many commonly used names in namespace `std`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeid(NeighborTile *) != typeid(FloorTile *)`. The signatures differ, so they don't count as "the same" method even if `NeighborTile` inherits from `FloorTile`.